# Apollo Server Context Request Property Does Not Exist

Tags: apollo-server

Here's my Apollo Server definition.

```
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: (async ({ req }) => {
      console.log(req);
      return {};
    }),
    csrfPrevention: true,
    cache: 'bounded',
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
    ],
  });
```

As we can see that `auth` property does exists in the `req` object but somehow when I tried to get the value, an error thrown `Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'` How can I retrieve the `auth` property?

```
<ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  ...,
  auth: { sub: '1234567890', name: 'John Doe', iat: 1516239022 },
  body: { query: 'query Query() {\n  }\n}\n' },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a little bit try and error, I can solve this issue by cast the context request to `express-jwt.Request` type as the code shown below,

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: (({ req }: { req: Request }) => {
    console.log(req.auth);
    return {};
  }),
  csrfPrevention: true,
  cache: 'bounded',
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
  ],
});
```